# Why does my site render so badly on a OnePlus 5T?

Tags: android, html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I'm experiencing a very strange responsiveness issue on a site I'm testing. I tested the site on four different devices.

On an iPhone XR, a Huawei Mate 20 Pro and a Huawei P30 Pro, the site more or less looks like this:

[image] [image]

However, using Firefox on a OnePlus 5T, the site looks like this:

[image]

It almost looks to me as if the device is completely ignoring the `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">` meta tag, but I don't know how to determine whether that's the case or not.

Here are the specs of the devices tested - their viewport sizes, resolutions and device pixel ratios:

```
Device:              Viewport:      Resolution:     Device Pixel Ratio:     
iPhone XR            414 x 896px    900 x 1947      2.1733333333333333333333333333333xDPR
Huawei Mate 20 Pro   360 x 780px    1440 x 3120     4xDPR 
Huawei P30 Pro       407 x 882px    1080 x 2340     2.6533333333333333333333333333333xDPR 
OnePlus 5T           314 x 681px    828 x 1792      2.63xDPR
```

At first glance of the specs it appears that the issue could be simply caused by the lower viewport size of the OnePlus 5T (obtained by dividing the resolution by the Device Pixel Ratio), but even when setting Firefox Responsive Mode to the same viewport size, the site still looks fine, and nothing near how it looks on the 5T itself.

The OnePlus 5T is older than the other devices, but having been released in 2017 it isn't exactly ancient either, and it seems necessary to support it since it's conceivable that users are still browsing the site on devices of that age, although maybe professional web devs would beg to differ on whether they would support it or not.